# Return object from list of objects based on variable in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects, of class `Author`, and I want to search this list of authors, based on one of the Author's properties, `name`, and when I receive a match I would like to return the instance of `Author` to be used to create an instance of another class, that requires `Author` as part of its constructor.

A better way to explain it would be:

```
author getAuthor(String arg_name)
{
  foreach (author auth in authorList)
  {
    if (auth.name == arg_name)
    {
      return auth;
    }
  }
}
```

Although I realize this specific code does work, is there a better way to perform this action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
return authorList.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.name == arg_name);
```

This would return `null` if any author with name doesn't matches with the parameter passed.

For your particular code, your check `if (auth == arg_name)` should give you compile time error. Your check should be `if (auth.name == arg_name)`

Comment: Works great! Much more compact than a `foreach`, thanks! Now to wait the 9 minutes to accept your answer :|

Comment: @sh3rifme, [start using LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) this would make your code compact and it is fun to work with :)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! I keep meaning to use more LINQ but i'm only just getting started with C# and have needed a good resource to guide my newb self, i'll check that link (pun intended) out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `public` property of `Name` in the `Author` you should be able to to get its value and compare it to the requested value (in your case `arg_name`). One way is to use `foreach`:

```
foreach (author auth as authorList)
  {
    if (auth.name == arg_name)
    {
      return auth;
    }
  }
```

Another way is to use Linq:

```
return authorList.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.name == arg_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ solution, although compact and elegant, is inefficient. You could use a dictionary, mapping from name, to index inside the list. Take into account that this solution is inefficient in adding/removing items, especially if they're added/removed from the middle of that list.... Think about which solution is more appropriate for you